# Issue in configuring virtual host in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, virtualhost, server.xml

I am facing issues in configuring virtual hosts in tomcat 7.

Till now, I have done the following:

- Added a **Host** element in the **server.xml** file with the appBase as the webapp folder that has my web application.

  ```
  <Host name="www.*myhostname*.com" appBase="my_webapp_folder_name" unpackWARs="true"     autoDeploy="true">
      <Context docBase="path_of_external_folder" path="/img" />
  </Host>
  ```
- Changed the defaultHost in the Catalina Engine.

  ```
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.*myhostname*.com">
  ```
- Created a webapp folder (**my_webapp_folder_name**) in catalina.home.  Also created a ROOT folder inside this webapp folder.
- Copied all the JSPs/HTML, class files, CSS etc inside this ROOT folder.
- Created a file ROOT.xml inside the catalina.home/conf/Catalina/myhostname folder with the following contents:

  ```
  <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/my_webapp_folder_name/ROOT" />
  ```

Am I missing something here? Because, after doing all the above, I am unable to connect using the host name.
But if I type in the IP address of the server, it works fine.

I cannot say whether there is any permissions related issue or not.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: A few minor errors in your configuration (that have no bearing on the problem you are encountering, but should be fixed): 1) Don't configure `<Context>` elements in `server.xml`: instead, use `[context].xml` in `conf/[service]/[hostname]/[context].xml` as you have done with `ROOT.xml`. 2) Never use the `path` attribute in your `<Context>` element: the context path will be taken from the name of the XML file.

Comment: One more thing: if you don't need to have more than one virtual host, don't bother modifying `server.xml` at all: Tomcat works perfectly find if you have the `defaultHost` set to `localhost` and only have that one `<Host>` defined. IMO it's a better configuration because you can support arbitrary hostnames as long s your DNS is set up correctly (which is of course the real problem you are encountering). Plus, it allows you to use a completely-default configuration which makes upgrades much easier.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a matter of name resolution. You must be able to resolve the www.myhostname.com.

You can add a name record if it is only to develop on your computer:

On Windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

On Linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

You can check the resolution with *nslookup* or *dig*.

Otherwise, set up your DNS to resolve www.myhostname.com to your Tomcat bind address.

Comment: So it means your server need to be accessible from the network (Internet or local network). Go to the authoritative server which is responsible of the domain "myhostname.com" and add a A or CNAME record that points to the IP Address of your Tomcat bind address. Does it sound familiar to you ?